# Redirection-web and mobile on sharing

Tags: javascript, angular, .htaccess, redirect

I am pretty close and aware about the strategy but lack coding stuff as I am unable to understand the regex/conditions of **.htaccess**

To make my question clear- I want to achieve whenever user uses my mobile application registered with **m.domain.com** or uses my website registered with  **web.domain.com**, I want to

> **redirect user according to the device/desktop/browsers he is opening.**

For e.g if he types m.domain.com on desktop size resolution, it should redirect them to web.domain.com and similarly for if he types anything on mobile browsers of iphone/android, it should redirect to m.domain.com

I have gone through blogs and google developers ideas and want to avoid js code/media query code since, it require my modules/files to be loaded and then run the scripts accordingly.

I have already read about the approaches using ***rel="canonical" and rel="alternate" but will it be enough as user agents?***
I want to achieve via htaccess but unable to write conditions accordingly.
It will be great for mentioning any links/sources or the code itself.

Small condition: I am using angular(please avoid PHP/ASP solutions)

Currently I have implemented this in my htaccess file for website and mobile dist folder respectively

```
mobile/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!(android|blackberry|googlebot- 
mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos)" [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

and on web/.htaccess

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.example.com/ [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You need to identify the "device/desktop/browsers" and add this information to your question. This is arguably the hardest part and hugely prone to error - since this information will change as time goes on. "on desktop size resolution" / "I want to achieve via htaccess" - this isn't something that can be done using `.htaccess`. In `.htaccess` the only things you can test for are elements of the HTTP request, eg. the user-agent string.

Comment: To be able to react directly to the window width in .htaccess, you’ll have to wait until [Client Hints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers#Client_hints) are actually a broadly implemented thing. As to how this currently works, you should do a bit more reading-up on the matter first. This basically all works based on checking the User-Agent header, and trying to match that to a specific set of known client devices, resp. their classification as mobile / tablet / desktop.

Comment: @CBroe agreed to you as per my reading, I came to know that this can be handled as per User-agent and we can rewrite condition on htaccess file accordingly. Please check for my answer which I have currently implemented.
What i am facing is on my seconday roots i.e. www.web.domain.com/xyz when i reload server throws me to Url not found error.